# Insertar salto de línea en texto, según una condición específica en Bash Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, edittext

tengo el siguiente texto que abro en el bash de Ubuntu para editarlo:

```
Fo, 68
Fo, 55Fm,   328
Fv, 273
Fv/Fm,  0.832
PAR,
TEMP,
Fs, 65
Fm',    91
èPS2,   0.286,
```

El texto se repite varias veces, pero esa es la unidad fundamental.

Quisiera insertar una línea en el primer Fm (en la segunda línea en este caso, no significa que esté solamente en la segunda línea). Para eso probé con:

```
    sed -e 's/Fm/\nFm/g'
```

Pero me inserta una línea también en Fv/Fm, luego de la barra /. Quisiera evitar esto último, pues me interesa que Fv/Fm quede tal cual como está.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dile a sed que lo haga solamente si este "Fm" está precedido por un dígito:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)Fm/\1\nFm/g' fichero
```

Ejemplo con un fichero simplificado:

```
$ cat fichero
hola
Fo, 55Fm,   328
Fv/Fm,  0.832
adios
$ sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)Fm/\1\nFm/g' fichero
hola
Fo, 55
Fm,   328
Fv/Fm,  0.832
adios
```

Comment: simple y  funciona! gracias